# Why does this htaccess work for a bit, and then doesnt?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect people to a new url of the login page,
It used to work, I made a few changes though, which kind of failed as I'm still trying to learn how to use htaccess, 
Anyhow I brought the very first code back, and for some awkward reason, it won't work anymore,

Here's the code:

```
# external redirect using R=301 to /login from /index.php?act=Login
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index\.php/?|)\?act=Login(&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/login? [R=301,L]
```

Is there any better way to achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the regular expression in the `RewriteCond` line. There is `(index\.php/?|)`. The pipe character is either to much and should be removed or you missed the second option for the sub-pattern.

Alternatively you should check whether a simple `Redirect` instruction will be enough instead of using complex rewrite rule for a possibly simple task.

Basic syntax of redirect is:

```
Redirect [status] <old-url> <new-url>
```

for your purposes the following should work:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=Login /login
```